# how to get Value from Checkinout of ms access database?

Tags: php, arrays, insert

Hi i am having a problem for several days now and I still cant figure what is wrong with the code, I am new to PHP. Below is my code

```
        $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }
    /*  dbconnection */

    $dbase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/msaccess/CrossChex.mdb";
    $user = "";
    $password = "";

    $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbase", $user, $password);
    $qry = "SELECT userid as id, CheckTime as check, min(CheckTime) as timein, max(CheckTime) as timeout FROM Checkinout group by userid, CheckTime";
    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$qry);
    while ($data[] = odbc_fetch_array($result));
    odbc_free_result($result);
    odbc_close($conn);

    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        $data_mysql = array(

            'userid' => $v['id'],
            'date_trans' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($v['check'])),
            'timein' => date("H:m", strtotime($v['timein'])),
            'timeout' => date("H:m", strtotime($v['timeout'])),

        );
    }
    $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($data_mysql));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', array_values($data_mysql));
    $values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_crosschex`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else
    { 
        echo $db->error;
    }
```

The code was getting data from access database from ANVIZ biometrics, and the timein and timeout is under one column. I need to align the Timein AND Timeout but instead the value of timein and timeout are separated by row i need both of them in single row.
Not Like this
Timein 8:00
 Timeout 5:00

and i need to be like this to be pass on the Mysql table
Timein | Timeout
 8:00 | 5:00
 Can someone help me tell what is the problem?

Comment: What should the code do? What errors are you getting?

Comment: SO Timein | Timeout will be in one field not 2 right

Comment: Hi @Ramyz... to be more clearer i will explain more. The CrossChecx.mdb has a rowname or filled name CheckTime the data of login and logout is stored there together what i want to achieve is i want them to be separated after that I will transfer to the MySQL that has Timein and Timeout Filled separately

Comment: but in this lines you getting them separately -> 'timein' => date("H:m", strtotime($v['timein'])), 'timeout' => date("H:m", strtotime($v['timeout'])),

Comment: @ramyz yes you are correct but. The problem is that the Timeout value is the same as Timein so i am confused what i have missed in the query

Comment: are u able to see access database table 'Checkinout ' , if so can you post that in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206164/discussion-between-ramyz-and-wyd-pilipinas).